# Treeview with parent/child issue loading by status

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, treeview

I have the following table structure it might not be a correct structure but unfortunatly that's what I was given.

```
id |  Name  | Parent  | Status
 1    First     0       Active
 2    Child     1       Active
 3    2Child    2       Inactive
```

Logic:

1. Load Root by Parent = 0 and Status
2. OnPopulate load child by parent ID and status for every levels after root

   my issue is if the status is "Inactive" and I want to see what options are inactive I can't because the first 2 options are active.  What I need is to be able to view in my treeview all the levels down to the option that is Inactive or Active.

I have tried the following sql statement

```
select distinct
        m.Id,
        m.Name,
        m.Parent,
        m.[Status]
from mytable m
where m.Parent = 3 and m.[Status] = 'I'
union
select 
        Id,
        Name,
        Parent,
        [Status]
from mytable
where ID in(select distinct
        o.ID
from mytable o
where o.ID = 3 and o.[Status] = 'I') and Parent = 3
```

I have ran out of ideas in sql and coding to figure this out..hope someone could guide me in the right direction..thanks

Also tried this in code:

```
    protected void mytree_TreeNodePopulate(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        //this is just a class that loads the values from db
        MYList templist = new ListSyFamily();
        templist.LoadAll();//(ddlStatus.SelectedValue, Convert.ToInt32(e.Node.Value));

        foreach (temp temp in templist)
        {
            if (temp.Status == ddlStatus.SelectedValue && temp.Parent == Convert.ToInt32(e.Node.Value))
            {
                TreeNode child = new TreeNode();
                child.Text = temp.Description;
                child.Value = temp.Id.ToString();
                if (child.ChildNodes.Count == 0)
                    child.PopulateOnDemand = true;

                child.ToolTip = "Ver sub-opciones";
                //child.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.SelectExpand;

                child.CollapseAll();

                e.Node.ChildNodes.Add(child);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this querying a MySQL database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how we handle this.

Assume that you have a class called MyRecord to hold each row of data from the DB:

```
public class MyRecord
{
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public int ParentId {get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    // The children of this node
    public MyRecordCollection Children = new MyRecordCollection();
}
```

Then you have a collection type to hold these records indexed by their id:

```
public class MyRecordCollection : System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, MyRecord>
{

}
```

Here is the code (retrieval from the DB not shown) to preprocess the records and then add them to the tree:

```
        MyRecordCollection cAllRecords;
        MyRecordCollection cParentRecords = new MyRecordCollection();

        // This is a method that just loads the records
        cAllRecords = LoadAllRecords();

        // Cycle through each of the records
        foreach (MyRecord oRecord in cAllRecords.Values)
        {
            if (oRecord.Id == 0)
            {
                // If the record is a parent record, add it to the list of parents
                cParentRecords.Add(oRecord.Id, oRecord);
            }
            else
            {
                // Otherwise, add the current record to its parent's list of children
                cAllRecords[oRecord.ParentId].Children.Add(oRecord.Id, oRecord);
            }
        }

        AddNodesToTree(cParentRecords, this.treeView1.Nodes);
```

And finally, the recursive method for adding the records to the tree:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// A recursive method to add all of the records to the specified collection of nodes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cRecords"></param>
    /// <param name="cNodes"></param>
    private void AddNodesToTree(MyRecordCollection cRecords, TreeNodeCollection cNodes)
    {
        foreach (MyRecord oRecord in cRecords.Values)
        {
            TreeNode oNode = new TreeNode();
            oNode.Text = oRecord.Name;
            oNode.Tag = oRecord;
            cNodes.Add(oNode);
            // Now add the node's children if any
            if (oRecord.Children.Count != 0)
            {
                AddNodesToTree(oRecord.Children, oNode.Nodes);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you!! I had somebody here help me out and he came up with the same solution slightly different but just bout the same. So glad for people like you and this great site! :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, If I were you I would just load the entire table into memory into a simple Collection of a light DTO class and work out your treeview in C#. That seems a lot easier than to try a lot of options in SQL.

Comment: to be honest with you I am so stumped I have no clue what you are suggesting..it sounds like a good solution but I can't come up with it..I'll edit my question to show what I've tried so far.